# I am unable to fix an UnavailableInvalidChannel Error

Tags: anaconda, gurobi, conda-forge

I am trying to create an environment in my Anaconda Navigator and I keep coming across this error.

```
UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid. channel name: gurobii channel url: http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobii error code: 404  You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed. Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state, and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

When I run --show channels I get:

```
channels:

- conda-forge
- http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobii
- http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi
- defaults
```

I have tried:

```
conda config --remove-key default_channels
```

And it will not work as I keep getting a CondaKeyError.

```
CondaKeyError: 'default_channels': key 'default_channels' is not in the config file
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how I can reconfigure my Anaconda?

Comment: `http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobii` is not an accessible URL. Why do you assume the error to be connected to the default channels? (since you tried to `conda config --remove-key default_channels`). Edit your `condarc` file and remove the wrong URL

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem as well. I'm using the following code to fix it:

```
conda config --remove-key channels
conda config --append channels conda-forge --append channels bioconda --append 
channels defaults
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. If possible, please 

[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78188452/edit)

your post to add further details, such as explanations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information in [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) - *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*  Thanks!